# GIF/IMG not removing from DOM (not a function?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif, removechild

So I'm continuing my Quiz application and my previous question gave me insight on how collections cannot use `.remove()`. I suppose my second question is, I've recently run into several problems getting the logo to do the same. How can I remove the logo image from the DOM if a loop didn't work and the default call didn't work.

I've tried to use `.removeChild` on the container, I've also tried to indirectly do it by doing `logoLoop.parentNode.removeChild(logoLoop);`both of these things resulted in the not a function error for both the `.remove()` & `.removeChild()`

In an attempt to access a remove function I was unaware about I changed the html for the logo so that the video was no longer an .mp4 and was now an `<img>` tag with a GIF. It didn't make a difference.

Is there a way to remove an image from the DOM completely?

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById("start");
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.button-56');
const buttonGrid = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");
const logoLoop = [document.getElementsByClassName("Logo")];
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("Container");


addGlobalEventListener("click", ".button-56", e => {
  startGame();
})

//Global Listener
function addGlobalEventListener(type, selector, callback) {
  document.addEventListener(type, e => {
    if (e.target.matches(selector)) callback(e)
  })
}

//Will use start game to remove button collection and logo this is where the error occurs. Buttons go away but not logo.
function startGame() {
  [...buttonGrid].forEach(button => button.remove());
  [...container].forEach(img => img.remove());
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: white cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
}
.Logo {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>QuiZA</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="frontlogo">QuiZA Logo </h1>
    <img src="assets\r1Logo.gif" alt="" class="Logo">
    <div class="grid">
      <button id="start" class="button-56" role="button">Start</button>
      <button class="button-56" role="button">Quiz List</button>
      <button class="button-56" role="button">Contact</button>
    </div>
    <!--Loading screen will start after this-->
    <div class="splash">
      <h1 class="splash-header">Press Here...</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not getting any error when I click on your buttons.

Comment: It looks like you left the problem code out of your code snippet.

Comment: Unrelated: URLs should use `/`, not ```\ ```. E.g. `js/app.js`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have shortened the css and I did not see that / \ error thank you. The error is I want the logo GIF to be deleted at the same time as the click start button.

Answer (score 0):

`logoLoop` is an array containing a `NodeList`. Arrays don't have a `.parentNode` property. You would need to loop over `logoLoop[0]` to access the DOM elements.

There's no reason to wrap it in an array. You should define and use it just like the other collections you create.

```
const logoLoop = document.querySelectorAll(".Logo")];
//...

logoLoop.forEach(logo => logo.remove());
```

BTW, if you use `querySelectorAll()` to create all your collections, you don't need to use `[...variable]` to loop over them. The collection returned by `querySelectorAll()` implements `.forEach()`.

Comment: I used the same loop and it still is not removed from the DOM

Comment: I don't even see the bad `logoLoop` code in the code snippet.